# how to get the row number of a sql query statement in php

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to get the value of rows depending on the sql select statement and the criteria.

Here is the code im using:

```
$fund = "SELECT COUNT(fundtid) from fund where fundtid='1'";
$result = mysql_query($fund, $connection);
if(!$result) {
die(mysql_error());
}
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result); 

print_r($row);
```

and it prints me this "Array ( [0] => 0 )"

Comment: so what are you trying to ask? You already have the code to do what you asked.  Secondly look at usuing mysqli or PDO rather than the old mysql_* functions.

Comment: i have the code, but it isnt working :S

Comment: Your query returns one row with the value 0. Hence you have no rows in your table `WHERE fundtid=1`, and hence `COUNT(fundtid)` is 0.  The code works fine, exactly as expected.

Comment: u are right, there is no id with that value, and the code seems works fine, but the result i get after i changed to another id it shows me result as Array ( [0] => 1 ) , where i want only 1

Comment: Please read [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php), you'll find all the answers you need.

Comment: Specifically, read [the manual on how Arrays work](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [php mysql_fetch_row manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php):

> Returns a **numerical array** that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead.

If you use `$row[0]` you have your result, e.g.: `print_r($row[0]);`